# if statement always false even if the value comparing must produce true result

Tags: php

Hi I was testing my program in reading lines of strings from a txt file.

I am going to transfer the result to an array but upon testing the if statement for converting the last array to a string via if and switch statement it always returning the false/else/default result.

my code is:

```
<?php
    $test = file('test.txt');
    foreach ($test as $row)
    {
        $temp = explode(' ', $row);
        echo "$row<br>";
        $id = (int)$temp[0];
        $date = substr($temp[1], 0, 2) . "-" . substr($temp[1], 2, 2) . "-" . substr($temp[1], 4, 4);
        $time = substr($temp[2], 0,2) .":". substr($temp[2], 2,2) .":00";
        $twt = (string)substr($row, 18);
        echo substr($row, 18);
        switch ($twt) {
            case 'I':
                echo "wew";
                break;

            default:
                echo "wow";
                break;
        }
        echo  "id: $id date: $date time: $time status: <br>";
    }
?>
```

The output of this is:

```
005 09012015 0811 I 
I wew id: 5 date: 09-01-2015 time: 08:11:00 status: 
005 09012015 1813 O 
O wew id: 5 date: 09-01-2015 time: 18:13:00 status: 
005 09022015 0756 I 
I wew id: 5 date: 09-02-2015 time: 07:56:00 status: 
005 09022015 1951 O 
O wew id: 5 date: 09-02-2015 time: 19:51:00 status:
```

Thanks for the help. I am kinda confused. I know that the $temp[3] array contains the 'I' value. but it stills going on the other output.

Comment: Am I blind? Where in here do you use `if` or `else`? What are you trying to do, and what is wrong with the output you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I posted the modified one.

the code I first using was

if ($twt == "I") {
   $status = "wow";
  }
  else
  {
   $status = "wew";
  }

Comment: But I keep on getting the else output even the value of the array was == 'I'

Comment: could you please attach the test.txt here.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($twt)` to verify you get exactly what you're expecting? Also, please consider renaming your variables with more meaningful names. Your code is shaping up to be very difficult to maintain.

Comment: Why even bother with substrings if you're already exploding the string? Just use `$temp[3]` and your problems may be caused by your type casting, have you tried it without?

Comment: I tried the var_dump($twt) and the output is `string(3) "I "`. 

here it the txt file.

005 09022015 1951 O
005 09032015 0810 I
005 09032015 1833 O
005 09042015 0812 I

Comment: Well there's your problem, you have a trailing space... Or two...

Comment: @VolkerK Sir Thanks for the parameter for the file. that solves my problem.

Comment: What? Who?  Are you lost? There's no one here by that name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[file()](http://docs.php.net/function.file) by default will keep the line break/feed characters. So instead of `I`, i.e. chr(73), you have three characters probably chr(73)chr(13)chr(10) or chr(73)chr(10)chr(13).
But there is a flag which you can pass as second parameter to have these characters removed (and also ignore otherwise empty lines as well).

```
$test = file('test.txt',  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
```

Comment: where did you saw the if statement ? :D

Comment: I didn't. After skimming over the comments it was clear that the question "text" can be ignored (the title even earlier). And `I tried the var_dump($twt) and the output is string(3) "I "` gave it away ;-)

Answer (score 0):

May be it contains white spaces or newline chars. Try this

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $twt));
```

or this

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $twt);
```

Comment: the first one is a bit overly complicated, no? `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $twt);` would do the trick just the same (though not completely identical) ;-) And the second probably would not fix it since the characters in question here are most likely line breaks or feeds not simple a space.